# Any Good Map Rendering Engines for SqlGeometry/SqlGeography

Tags: sql-server, vector, rendering

Can anyone suggest good map rendering engines for MS SQL Server Spatial types (SqlGeometry/SqlGeography)?  By rendering, I mean plot the geometries to a common image format such as png or jpeg with very simple symbology.

The 2 I have experimented with thus far are:
1.  SharpMap
2.  MapServer with the MSSql plugin

I just want to see if there is anything else out there that I might have missed.

Comment: +1, I'm curious how sharpmap and mapserver compare for rendering. (sample image results would be nice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MapGuide OS](http://mapguide.osgeo.org/) has the ability to serve MSSQL Server 2008 data.

Answer (score 4):

GeoServer?
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/sqlserver.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a built in renderer in Management Studio.
I missed it for a while.

/Nicklas

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  But I don't believe you can save images from the viewer or control symbology, can you?

Comment: no, I think you are right. just a renderer.

Comment: I found, to get the "Spatial results" tab to show up next to Results and Messages, the result set had to be just the geography column, then it worked great.  Also, make sure your polygons are defined in counter-clockwise order, else they won't show.

Answer (score 1):

FME has the capability too

http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Web_Map_Tile_Cache_in_SQL_Server

Answer (score 1):

Manifolds MapServer object can render images from SqlServer geometry (or any other spatial format that it can handle).

It is generally used IMS applications, but can just as easily be used for just image rendering.

http://www.manifold.net/doc/hid_scriptitem_mapserver.htm

Answer (score 1):

[Mapnik](http://mapnik.org) could possibly connect to MS SQL Server spatial geometries, it uses the well known GDAL/OGR lib.

Comment: Laurent - do you know of a link to any documentation or tutorials that show Mapnik and SQL Server working together? While I agree that it should be possible via OGR (either directly or perhaps via a virtual layer interface), in practice I've never got this to work.

Comment: Sorry no, i presumed too quickly, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Mapnik is the best option, it renders the most beautiful maps this time

Answer (score 0):

[MapSurfer.NET](http://mapsurfernet.com/) is an advanced cartographic framework for producing beautiful and readable maps. It supports both Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and 2012.